# Mysql query for already booked count in between dates

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Developing booking website in cakephp. Im little struck in query writing.

If user tries to book from "2015-12-11 08:00:00" to "2015-12-11 16:00:00".

how to i select from table that it is already booked or not.

Ex: If already one person booked from 6am to 9am means it should not allow. 
I have used below query but its not fetching correctly i think.

```
SELECT * FROM `items` 
WHERE ((`fromdate` < '2015-12-11 08:00:00' AND `todate` < '2015-12-11 16:00:00') 
OR (`fromdate` > '2015-12-11 08:00:00' AND `todate` > '2015-12-11 16:00:00')) AND status=1;
```

Comment: This is not much cakephp related quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` 
WHERE ((`fromdate` between '2015-12-11 08:00:00' AND '2015-12-11 16:00:00' 
OR (`todate` between '2015-12-11 08:00:00' AND '2015-12-11 16:00:00')) AND status=1;
```

Comment: Looks a little over-complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM items i
 WHERE i.fromdate < '2015-12-11 16:00:00' 
   AND i.todate   > '2015-12-11 08:00:00' 
   AND i.status = 1;
```